# java.util.Scanner#findWithHorizon throws OutOfMemory exception on 32Mb input stream

Tags: java

Search string '4914904' exists at the tail of the stream.

Here's the code

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(xmlInputStream, "UTF-8");
    if(sc.findWithinHorizon('4914904', 0) != null) { // <--- exception is thrown here
    }
```

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: That doesn't look like valid Java code to me... what type do you expect `'4914904'` to be?

Comment: How much memory do you have?  If the String is not found it could read the entire file into memory consuming up to 4 times the size of the file. (worst case)

Comment: @Jon. You're right. This is not Java, but Groovy. However java won't work also. 

@Peter I've 16Gb, but I don't wanna let this simple operation to use all my memory ;) I thought Scanner is optimized somehow to read from huge streams. I guess that code runs with -Xmx512m by default and dies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the API for Scanner, you will see that if you pass the argument 0 to [findWithinHorizon](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#findWithinHorizon%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) that it will read the entire buffer at once.

Since you don't do anything with the value from this I see a few options.

Try changing to [useDelimiter(String pattern)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter%28java.lang.String%29) and then call `if(sc.hasNext())` which may help some with the memory footprint.

If you have XML, use an XML parser instead of a text scanner.

You could consider writing a custom method which parses the input stream one line at a time and perform the search. That way you don't have to read in the full buffer.

Increase the memory you give the jvm when it starts `-Xmx256m`

On a side note: Don't re-write the code when you post here. Just copy and paste.

Comment: I'll be writing my own parser then. Thanks.

Comment: DOM XML parser dies and SAX is not what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Use `-Xmx256m` when starting Java, it will give the JVM more heap space.

You also might want to consider using an XML parsing library instead of Scanner, if you're dealing with XML. A streaming API like SAX or StAX are the best bet for a big input.

Comment: I tired with Sax, but it's slow in my case. Thanks for suggesting